# How to insert page/post specific script in header and footer in WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress, header, footer

How to insert page/post specific script in header and footer in WordPress?

I need to insert the script on a specific page or post. For Example, I will insert different codes in different pages/posts. The codes will not appear in all the pages/posts.

Comment: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/256094/how-to-enqueue-javascript-for-specific-wordpress-pages-only

Answer (score 0):

You can use is_page() function:

```
is_page( $page = '' );
```

$page
(int|string|array) (Optional) Page ID, title, slug, or array of such.

For example if your page id is 1954

```
if( is_page( $page = 1954 ) ){
 your specific code for this page here..
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can Do it via Slug of post or page or id of post/page using...

**1. is_single()** for post

**2. is_page()** for page

you can add or functions also if you want to add that code in multiple pages but specific pages only.
here is code...

if (is_page('home') || is_page('contact') || is_page('45')

**Example 1....**

```
 <?php if (is_page('home')): ?>
    <!--home page add custom JS-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/Scripts/customJS.js"></script>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

**Example 2...**

```
<?php if (is_page(346) ):?>
    <!-- Google Analytics Content Experiment code here -->
        ...
    <!-- End of Google Analytics Content Experiment code here -->
<?php endif; ?>
```